# Decreasing size of ViewState from DataGrid

Tags: asp.net, datagrid, viewstate

I am trying to decrease the load in ViewState that is coming from my DataGrid, but it is not working as I expected. When my page initially runs (and my datagrid is empty), it's viewstate is about 1794 bytes. When I fill my datagrid with `EnableViewState="true"`, ViewState comes out to 4,074,656 bytes, and when I fill the datagrid with *the same data* but `EnableViewState="false"`, viewstate comes out to 2,477,356 bytes. I know this number is almost cut in half, but it is still a large number (and is proportionate to the size of the grid). Without anything coming from the datagrid, I would expect this to definitely be less than 10,000 (not much larger than the original 1794).. why is it still so high? Is there something else I must do to decrease the viewstate load coming from my datagrid? By the way, the datagrid when filled has about 1600 rows and 27 columns.

Comment: Fetch only the records you need for the GridView/DataGrid "page"
 you are on.

Comment: I'm not using pages. The client doesn't want paging to be implemented here.

Comment: Have you decoded the ViewState to see what exactly is getting stuffed in there?  That might help you find exactly how to shrink it down.  [Here's a base64 ViewState decoder](http://ignatu.co.uk/ViewStateDecoder.aspx)

Comment: @hmqcnoesy I know that it has to do with the datagrid because the size is directly proportionate the size of the datagrid; with or without EnableViewState being disabled. Good idea though, I will have to check it out when I get the chance. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I realized the DataTable I retrieved from my data layer class (used to bind my DataGrid to) was also being stored in `ViewState[]` for sorting purposes (very bad practice), which I just found out stores all of its data in the `__VIEWSTATE` hidden field.

It was being stored in `ViewState[]` because I was too lazy to store/retrieve the search option fields and re-query for sorting, not realizing the consequences. Basically, with my DataGrid having `EnableViewState="true"`, my `__VIEWSTATE` was doubling in size.. I learned a lot from this mistake, and I hope anyone else that stumbles across this learns something too.